# Batch: How to store values encountered during a regular expression search & replace (repl.bat)

Tags: batch-file, replace, store, batch-processing

Using Batch, I'm looking for a way to (1) search for a regular expression pattern and (2) store variables within that pattern... so I can use those variables while doing a search and replace.

I've been using REPL.BAT, which was created by [@dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) ([original REPL.BAT post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855) and [earliest StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir/16735079#16735079)).  Here's an example of the scenario.

I search a document for the occurence of the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("rwbyrd")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password")
```

And replace it with...

```
login("rwbyrd","password")
```

Using the following Batch code:

```
type %filename% | repl "\sdriver\.find_element_by_id\(\x22username\x22\)\.send_keys\(\x22rwbyrd\x22\)\s*driver\.find_element_by_id\(\x22password\x22\)\.send_keys\(\x22password\x22\)"       "login(\x22rwbyrd\x22,\x22password\x22)" MX >%filename%.new
```

NOTE:  \x22 = Hex for double quotes

What I am looking for is a way to store the [username] 'rwbyrd' and [password] 'password' values from the code I'm searching for & use those values when doing a replace.  I'd like to find a way to achieve this within the REPL.BAT command, but I will take what I can get :).  Does anyone know how to achieve this?  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: @dbenham - really cool feature, thanks!  I'd found a way to get what I wanted working, but this addition to your script would definitely reduce the amount of code necessary.  I'll give it a try later today and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done this already, I strongly recommend you execute the following commands from the command prompt:

To get help specific to REPL.BAT:

```
repl /?
```

To get help about the JScript regular expressions used by REPL.BAT (opens up MicroSoft documentation in your web browser)

```
repl /?regex
```

To get help about the replace submatch features - the "variables" you are looking for (opens up MicroSoft documentation in your web browser)

```
repl /?replace
```

I replaced the leading `\s` with `\b` (word boundry) in your search regex. I also use un-escaped parentheses to capture the username and password values so that I can use them in the replacement string. The `.*?` matches the content within the parentheses literals (non-greedy match). One cosmetic change was to use `\q` instead of `\x22`.

```
type %filename% | repl "\bdriver\.find_element_by_id\(\qusername\q\)\.send_keys\((.*?)\)\s*driver\.find_element_by_id\(\qpassword\q\)\.send_keys\((.*?)\)" "login($1,$2)" MX >%filename%.new
```

**Update**

Based on OP's comment, and Aacini's answer, I've updated REPL.BAT to accept a J option to specify the replacement value as a JScript expression.

The following example will convert the username to upper case:

```
type %filename% | repl "\bdriver\.find_element_by_id\(\qusername\q\)\.send_keys\((.*?)\)\s*driver\.find_element_by_id\(\qpassword\q\)\.send_keys\((.*?)\)" "'login('+$[1].toUpperCase()+','+$[2]+')'" MXJ >%filename%.new
```

See http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37855#p37855 for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @dbenham.  I hadn't gotten around to replacing the '\x22' with '\q' in my batch file.  I was also having trouble understanding how to achieve my desired result even after reading the links you had listed in the documentation of your script.  Your suggestion worked as usual.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have another question for you somewhat related to this topic.

Would there be a way to include a method to take something I stored during my search with `.*?` and change the case (i.e. Uppercase) of it before using it in my replace statement?  Based on what I've read so far, it sounds like I'm going to have to capture those values ahead of time and use an uppercase script before inserting them into the file.  I thought I'd ask just to be sure though.

Comment: @rwbyrd - Certainly not with the current REPL.BAT. But that is an interesting idea. Such a feature is entirely possible because the JScript replace() function that I use allows for specification of a function to take control of the replace mechanics. But I don't have any plans to implement such a feature.

Comment: This idea is very interesting! See the edit in my answer below.

Comment: @rwbyrd - After seeing Aacini's answer, I was able to quickly modify REPL.BAT to use JScript expressions. See the updated answer.

Comment: Can the 'J' option work with other options?  So for the following...

'if "Serial #" == driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.leftcol").text: break'

... I want to achieve the following result...

'expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.leftcol'), "Serial #")'

Should this work:

'type filename.py | repl "\bif (.*?) \=\= driver\.find_element_by_(.*?)\(\q(.*?)\q\)\.text\: break" "expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.$[2].toUpperCase(),'$3'),$1)" JMX >filenameNEW.py'

???

Comment: @rwbyrd - sure it can work, especially since there are no more options than the prior example. But your code is wrong - you need to concatenate string constants with your submatch values. If you can't get it to work, then ask a new question. Also, check out the latest update to REPL.BAT.

Answer (score 2):

When you use regular expressions you must note that `\s` metacharacter matches "Any white-space character. This includes space, tab, and form feed.", but NOT a CR+LF pair end-of-line characters, so you must include they in the regular expression.

Exist another program similar to dbenham's REPL.BAT; it is called FindRepl.bat and you may download it from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697). In FindRepl replacement string you may include $1, $2, etc. to get the value of matched "sub-expressions" enclosed in parentheses. For example, this input file:

```
Any previous line
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("rwbyrd")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password")
any posterior line
```

... processed with FindRepl.bat via this line:

```
type filename.txt | findrepl /Q:' "\sdriver\.find_element_by_id\('username'\)\.send_keys\('(.*)'\)\r\n\s*driver\.find_element_by_id\('password'\)\.send_keys\('(.*)'\)" "login('$1','$2')"
```

... produce this output:

```
Any previous line
   login("rwbyrd","password")
any posterior line
```

You may test if the same regular expression produce the same output in REPL.BAT.

PS - I strongly encourage you to see the regular expression documentation suggested by `FindRepl /?`.

---

**EDIT**: I borrowed the idea stated on dbenham's answer comments and used it to implement the processing of the matched substrings via a JScript expression placed in the replacement text in my FindRepl.bat program; the only requirement to do that is to include the new /J (JScript expression) switch and correctly write the replacement expression.

The modification in the program was relatively simple and required just 5 *new* lines, that included 2 new lines of documentation; I used the example at [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.84).aspx) as base to complete the modification. The listing below is the result of comparing the original and new versions of FindRepl.bat program via `fc /N FindRepl.bat "FindRepl Modified.bat"` command:

```
Comparing files FindRepl.bat and FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
***** FindRepl.bat
   28:  FINDREPL [/I] [/V] [/N] rSearch [/E:rEndBlk] [/O:s:e] [/B:rBlock] [/$:s1...]
   29:           [[/R] [/A] sReplace] [/Q:c] [/S:sSource]
   30:  
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
   28:  FINDREPL [/I] [/V] [/N] rSearch [/E:rEndBlk] [/O:s:e] [/B:rBlock] [/$:s1...]
   29:           [[/R] [{/J|/A}] sReplace] [/Q:c] [/S:sSource]
   30:  
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
   39:    /R         Prints only replaced lines, instead of all file lines.
   40:    /A         Specifies that sReplace has alternative values matching rSearch.
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
   39:    /R         Prints only replaced lines, instead of all file lines.
   40:    /J         Specifies that sReplace is a JScript expression, not a string.
   41:    /A         Specifies that sReplace has alternative values matching rSearch.
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
   48:  The replacement string may use $ to retrieve saved submatched substrings. See:
   49:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.84).aspx
   50:  Use /A switch to insert several values separated by pipe in rSearch/sReplace.
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
   49:  The replacement string may use $ to retrieve saved submatched substrings. See:
   50:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.84).aspx   If /J switch
   51:  is given, the replacement text is an expression that must use submatched $.
   52:  Use /A switch to insert several values separated by pipe in rSearch/sReplace.
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
   89:  // FINDREPL [/I] [/V] [/N] rSearch [/E:rEndBlk] [/O:s:e] [/B:rBlock] [/$:s1...]
   90:  //          [[/R] [/A] sReplace] [/Q:c] [/S:source]
   91:  
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
   91:  // FINDREPL [/I] [/V] [/N] rSearch [/E:rEndBlk] [/O:s:e] [/B:rBlock] [/$:s1...]
   92:  //          [[/R] [{/J|/A}] sReplace] [/Q:c] [/S:source]
   93:  
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
  105:      justReplaced = options.Exists("R"),
  106:      replace      = undefined,
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
  107:      justReplaced = options.Exists("R"),
  108:      JSexpr       = false,
  109:      replace      = undefined,
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
  159:     if ( quote != undefined ) replace = replace.replace(eval("/"+quote+"/g"),'"');
  160:     if ( options.Exists("A") ) {  // Enable alternation replacements from "Se|ar|ch" to "Re|pla|ce"
  161:        var Asearch = search.split("|"),
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
  162:     if ( quote != undefined ) replace = replace.replace(eval("/"+quote+"/g"),'"');
  163:     if ( options.Exists("J") ) {  // Replacement text is a JScript expression with the return value of function($0,$1,$2)
  164:        JSexpr = true;
  165:     } else if ( options.Exists("A") ) {  // Enable alternation replacements from "Se|ar|ch" to "Re|pla|ce"
  166:        var Asearch = search.split("|"),
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
  335:           if ( match(fileContents[lineNumber-1],search) ) {
  336:              WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(fileContents[lineNumber-1].replace(search,replace));
  337:              result++;
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
  340:           if ( match(fileContents[lineNumber-1],search) ) {
  341:              WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(fileContents[lineNumber-1].replace(search,JSexpr?function($0,$1,$2){return(eval(replace))}:replace));
  342:              result++;
*****

***** FindRepl.bat
  345:     } else {  // Replace on entire file
  346:        WScript.Stdout.Write(fileContents.replace(search,replace));
  347:     }
***** FINDREPL MODIFIED.BAT
  350:     } else {  // Replace on entire file
  351:        WScript.Stdout.Write(fileContents.replace(search,JSexpr?function($0,$1,$2){return(eval(replace))}:replace));
  352:     }
*****
```

Previous listing should be enough to obtain the modified version of FindRepl.bat. This way, in order to replace the first matched subexpression to uppercase letters, just use:

```
type filename | findrepl "(.*)" /J "$1.toUpperCase()"
```

This feature is very powerful, because the replacement text may be *any* valid JScript expression that may use any character processing method. For example:

```
type filename | findrepl "before (.*) after" /J "'before'+$1.substr(0,4).toUpperCase()+'after'"
```

You may even introduce a much more complex JScript replacement expression that include several assignments (to auxiliary variables) via comma JScript operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Aacini!  I'd actually stumbled upon this script a few days ago and planned to experiment with it when I got a chance.  Again, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: +1, Sweet! - Good idea to use eval() - it makes using JScript expressions quite simple. However, you should use the arguments object instead of defining named parameters. The number of arguments varies depending on the number of captured submatches. I've updated REPL.BAT, and my answer above using these techniques.

Comment: @Aacini - Awesome, thank you very much!  I intend to test your script as well with some other projects I'm working on.  I'll get back to you with any comments/questions I have.